# file is universal (5 slices) but does not contain a(n) i386 slice

Tags: xcode, xcode6

My app was working correctly until a few hours ago. I was just making some changes to the class library and nothing that might have caused this problem (AFAIK)

This is the build error I get ... why is looking for i386? prior to that I was getting a similar error for x86-64. I'm far from an expert in this area and so far google has not helped.

ld: file is universal (5 slices) but does not contain a(n) i386 slice: /Users/xxxx/Sites/my_xcode_projects/CREW app/CREW Emergency Preparedness/CREW Emergency Preparedness/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a file '/Users/xxxx/Sites/my_xcode_projects/CREW app/CREW Emergency Preparedness/CREW Emergency Preparedness/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I removed GoogleAnalytics from my app and it builds without problem ... but i have no idea why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to clean `Command + Shift + K` your project and then add the google analytics library. Xcode do sometimes behaves in funny manner.